# how to create a notification with small image using a String image path in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

I have tried to watch a lot of tutorials that show how to implement natification with big picture using big picture style information like this

```
var bigPictureStyleInformation = BigPictureStyleInformation(
  FilePathAndroidBitmap(attachmentPicturePath),
  contentTitle: '<b>Attached Image</b>',
  htmlFormatContentTitle: true,
  summaryText: 'Test Image',
  htmlFormatSummaryText: true,
);
```

but what I really want is to show notification with small image in Android like this

[image]

how to make notification like that if I have a string image path? so it seems I have to download the image from server then 'attach' it to notification. how to do that

Answer (score 1):

For future users:

If you want to have the same image as shown in the attached image, you should pass `largeIcon` for `AndroidNotificationDetails`.

The code is something like this(This example shows both large icon and big image together):

This example is from [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications/example).

```dart
  Future<String> _downloadAndSaveFile(String url, String fileName) async {
    final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final String filePath = '${directory.path}/$fileName';
    final http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    final File file = File(filePath);
    await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
    return filePath;
  }

Future<void> _showBigPictureNotification() async {
    final String largeIconPath = await _downloadAndSaveFile(
        'https://via.placeholder.com/48x48', 'largeIcon');
    final String bigPicturePath = await _downloadAndSaveFile(
        'https://via.placeholder.com/400x800', 'bigPicture');
    final BigPictureStyleInformation bigPictureStyleInformation =
        BigPictureStyleInformation(FilePathAndroidBitmap(bigPicturePath),
            largeIcon: FilePathAndroidBitmap(largeIconPath),
            contentTitle: 'overridden <b>big</b> content title',
            htmlFormatContentTitle: true,
            summaryText: 'summary <i>text</i>',
            htmlFormatSummaryText: true);
    final AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
            'big text channel id', 'big text channel name',
            channelDescription: 'big text channel description',
            styleInformation: bigPictureStyleInformation);
    final NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0, 'big text title', 'silent body', platformChannelSpecifics);
  }
```